# Certain sort of cartographic maps

Tags: word-request

I cannot find the right word for the usual map that has enlarged areas due to
overwhelming usage of some aspect in that area.
An example may be the poverty, spoken the Czech Language which would give a great area
in the surrounding of the Czech Republic or usage of beer worldwide.

What's the right name I can search for in a library?

Comment: Is this the same sort of thing as a [***sensory homunculus***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortical_homunculus) (distorted representation of the human body based on where the body has more sensory nerves)? That's certainly nothing to do with how standard map projections make, say, Canada look much bigger than it really is, as an artifact of representing a spherical surface on a flat sheet of paper.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's it. I just cannot find the right word for Atlas instead of Human sensory homunuculus. Is there an English word for this or what can I search for on Amazon.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a technical word for this (it took a bit of searching to find, and it doesn't have much currency for not specialists)  That word is [Cartogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartogram) or "Anamorphic map".  In such maps the size of a region is distorted to represent some value associated with that region, such as population or GDP.

[image]

This cartogram, from Wikipedia, represents population.

As this is technical, a non-specialist would not know this word. You could call it a "map in which area is proportional to population"

Comment: Very good. I cannot find anything under this name on Amazon.com, why ?

Comment: Because Amazon.com is not a specialist supplier to the map making industry, but sells to non-specialists like me.  This is a technical term, so you would not expect it to be used in a generic forum like Amamzon

Comment: So could you find the usage of the Czech Language cartogram ?

Comment: [here](https://worldmapper.org/maps/czech-language/) is one.

Comment: No. but evidentially you can.